# LCD shield submenu

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd, shields

I need to make an app that does various functions regarding IR signals (remote-like)
I need to create a sub menu in order for me to access multiple functionalities.

[Arduino-Uno-Menu-Template](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Uno-Menu-Template/)

I used the link above to create a menu and it works great! The problem is I can not do a sub menu without messing with the loop that display the original one. Any ideas?

This is the code I got so far:

https://pastebin.com/Vh5R2JVp

I'm trying in menuItem1() function to add a routine to create the submenu.
I tried to use a variable that changes when the menu does but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written so far?

Comment: The code is the same one as the one from the link I've provided. I just modified the items so it would fit what my menu needs. The link above is a simple template but has no submenus whatsoever. That's what I need !

Comment: I added the code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do (but there are many solutions):

- Keep a variable (e.g. `subMenu` that has the state of the current menu option selected (make this an `enum`).
- Whenever a sub menu is entered, assign the `subMenu` variable with the current sub menu value.
- Use a `switch` around the current `switch` statement for first switching subMenu (make different functions for clearity).

So the pseudo code would look like

```
enum ESubMenu { MainMenu, Page1, Page2 };
ESubMenu subMenu;

void setup()
{
  subMenu =  MainMenu;
}

void loop()
{
   switch (subMenu)
   {
   case MainMenu : showMainMenu() ; break;
   case Page1Menu: showPage1Menu(); break;
   case Page2Menu: showPage2Menu(); break;
   }
}

void showMainMenu()
{
   if (`sub menu 1 selected`)
   {
      subMenu = Page1Menu; 
   }
   else if (`sub menu 2 selected')
   {
      subMenu = Page2Menu;
   }
   else
   {
      // Show/handle main menu
   }
}

void ShowPage1()
{
   if `back' 
   {
     subMenu = MainMenu;
   }
   else
   {
      // Show/handle page 1 menu options
   }
}
```

Comment: I will try this. I hope I understood the concept. I am new in Arduino

Comment: What type should my variable be?

Comment: Of type ESubMenu

Comment: It didn't work. I think it's probably because of how the loop works

Comment: It's not a full code, you have to add code for getting the buttons yourself; also I couldn't test it; it's more like a pseudo code template

Comment: I know, I've tried to adapt it to the menu template. For some reason it won't let me come back to the first menu page. I believe it's because of the loop.

Comment: If submenu is MainMenu, it should show the main menu, maybe you can add some print statements to print out the value of submenu to see if it has the expected value. Also in a submenu, when going back, make sure to assign MainMenu to subMenu to revert back to the main menu.

Comment: Can I show you the code in some way?

Comment: Add it to your question (so anybody can respond)